# Exporting data with Display Tag and external pagination

Tags: java, jsp, reporting, export-to-excel, displaytag

We use the [Display Tag Library](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/) to display grid data in our JSP's.

We use [external](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/tut_externalSortAndPage.html) sorting and pagingation.  And we also use the library's [export](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/export.html) feature to allow exporting to Excel or PDF.

Issue is the export is only exporting the data on the current set of results (ie: rows 20-40) while we want the export to include all rows.

Anyone know how to do this?

I believe this works automatically when you are NOT using external sorting and pagination as Display Tag has the entire resultset and includes it all in the export.  However we are using the external sorting/pagination..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Appears this is indeed a [known issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/DISPL-361).

Our solution

```
//Determine if user is doing an export
boolean export = request.getParameter(TableTagParameters.PARAMETER_EXPORTING) != null;

if (export) {
    //Return entire list
} else {
    //Return paginated list
}
```

Comment: :it is not working for me. only half of content are exported.

Comment: Worked for me just now, using DisplayTag 1.2. Thanks!

Comment: You must set partialList="false" in your displaytag. <display:table partialList="false"